# add search for list on android!

Tags: android, search, listview, listactivity

hello
iam a novice to android app development i recently leant how to implement list activity
i have a application which shows the all states of USA

now i have to add a simple search facility to this app when required state name is typed 
it shud display the state name and print a msg when it doesn't find suitable name!!

```
 package shashi.android.Statelist;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class Statelist extends ListActivity {
 String[] listofstates = {     "Alabama: AL",
      "Alaska: AK",
      "Arizona: AZ",
      "Arkansas: AR",
      "California: CA",
      "Colorado: CO",
      "Connecticut: CT",
      "Delaware: DE",
      "Florida: FL",
      "Georgia: GA",
      "Hawaii: HI",
      "Idaho: ID",
      "Illinois: IL",
      "Indiana: IN",
      "Iowa: IA",
      "Kansas: KS",
      "Kentucky: KY",
      "Louisiana: LA",
      "Maine: ME",
      "Maryland: MD",
      "Massachusetts: MA",
      "Michigan: MI",
      "Minnesota: MN",
      "Mississippi: MS",
      "Missouri: MO",
      "Montana: MT",
      "Nebraska: NE",
      "Nevada: NV",
      "New Hampshire: NH",
      "New Jersey: NJ",
      "New Mexico: NM",
      "New York: NY",
      "North Carolina: NC",
      "North Dakota: ND",
      "Ohio: OH",
      "Oklahoma: OK",
      "Oregon: OR",
      "Pennsylvania: PA",
      "Rhode Island: RI",
      "South Carolina: SC",
      "South Dakota: SD",
      "Tennessee: TN",
      "Texas: TX",
      "Utah: UT",
      "Vermont: VT",
      "Virginia: VA",
      "Washington: WA",
      "West Virginia: WV",
      "Wisconsin: WI",
      "Wyoming: WY"
 };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listofstates));
    }
}
```

the search i need. e.g.: to retrieve the typed text and return my search response

So, basically i need just the design, not it's functionality.

Can someone tell me if i can use this bar only for my personal data, not a general search from internet or the hole phone, and i would appreciate link for a simple and clear tutorial, because i couldn't found anything concrete till now.

like only the result for finding the typed text or else printing the "result not found" msg

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `AutoCompleteTextView`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html

> **Auto Complete**
>
> To create a text entry widget that provides auto-complete suggestions, use the AutoCompleteTextView widget. Suggestions are received from a collection of strings associated with the widget through an ArrayAdapter.
>
> In this tutorial, you will create a AutoCompleteTextView widget that provides suggestions for a country name.

Comment: but what if i want simple search with just a msg saying keyword not found when required pattern dint match instead of auto complete

Comment: Search feature which will return a State and a message if the state is not valid.

Comment: @shashi - I realize I was suggesting an alternative that is different from what you were asking for.  I just wanted to make you aware a possible alternate approach if you weren't aware - especially since its pre-built and built into Android.  If it doesn't work for your situation, no problem - might be helpful to a future OP with a similar problem.

Comment: @ Bert F thank you for ur response 1st and yeah the alternative works good

Comment: @ bert but i really have no scope for that alternative in my app i have been assigned this work and i just want a simple search like a web page search but instead of comparing the data from datatbase and the search bar i want it to compare the array and search bar !!